# Unable to covert .txt file in ANSI to UTF-8 in windows

Tags: encoding

We are using Windows Server2008R2, can anyone help me in converting a .txt file in ANSI to UTF-8 formate in the command line. I am not finding the correct correct one.

Thanks

Comment: Open the text file in Notepad, and Save As, choose UTF-8 in the Encoding drop down.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1163753/converting-text-file-to-utf-8-on-windows-command-prompt

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate?
https://superuser.com/questions/1163753/converting-text-file-to-utf-8-on-windows-command-prompt

You can easily do this with PowerShell:

```
Get-Content .\test.txt | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 test-utf8.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff for your response, but in our batch process this is one of the piece we need to include in middle. Thinking if something can be used for regular batch scripting or windows commands.

Comment: Hi @Raj - I do not believe that this is easily achievable using only batch.

Powershell is included by default with Windows OS's since Win7/2008R2, at some point it is going to become an accepted regular 'windows command'.

If powershell does not appeal to you, cscript has been included by default in Windows since XP?